# How can I restrict the insert values of certain columns based on another in postgres

Tags: postgresql, constraints

I have a table here and I want to ensure that certain inserts are blocked.

```
CREATE TABLE Creature (
  species TEXT,
  name TEXT,
  arms INTEGER,
  legs INTEGER
);
```

When inserting into this table, every species should have the same number of arms and legs as any other entry with the same species.

```
INSERT INTO Creatures VALUES ('Human', 'John', 2, 2);
INSERT INTO Creatures VALUES ('Human', 'Steve', 2, 2);
INSERT INTO Creatures VALUES ('Human', 'Mark', 0, 4); -- should not work as humans have 2 arms and 2 legs
```

I have tried using check constraints but I am not sure how to check existing tables values if they already exist.

Comment: That's not sustainable.  What if someone inserts the first "Goat" and accidentally specifies 5 legs?  Does that mean all goats have to have 5 legs?  Better to have fixed constraints in the table definition.

Comment: I know. Its for a school assignment so its not terribly well planned out. Is there any way I can implement something like this though?

Comment: The answer below is the right way to handle it.  Your table is not 3rd Normal Form.  There's no way to have insert criteria that are based on existing rows.

Comment: You could write an SQL function to do all the inserts and do the checking there, but that won't prevent rogue INSERTs.

Answer (score 1):

Normalize. First create another table `species` in which you store the number of arms and legs *per species*.

```
CREATE TABLE species
             (id serial,
              name text,
              arms integer,
              legs integer,
              PRIMARY KEY (id));
```

Then only have a foreign key referencing the species in `creatures`.

```
CREATE TABLE creature
             (id serial,
              species integer,
              name text,
              PRIMARY KEY (id),
              FOREIGN KEY (species)
                          REFERENCES species
                                     (id));
```

Answer (score 0):

While this seems like a pretty lousy design for more than one reason, you can still do it.  You would use an EXCLUDE constraint.

```
create extension btree_gist;

alter table creature add constraint consistent_limbs 
    exclude using gist (species with =, arms with <>, legs with <>);
```